# What's the movie with the "Giger" Helmet?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember a movie I saw years ago on the SciFi channel (late 90's) where the main character had some kind of alien helmet he would wear, that would turn him into some kind of superhero named "Giger".

I am totally failing on finding anything about this movie, (It all comes up with H.R.Giger obit's and collections).  Anyone remember this?

Comment: Is "Giger" the correct spelling or are you assuming? How is it pronounced? Depending on pronunciation it could be "Giga" or "Geiger" (as in Hans Geiger) or something completely different.

Comment: Could you share more details about the movie that would make it easier to identify?

Comment: I think you mean the Guyver, but in that the alien device was integrated into his body, not a helmet he put on.

Comment: Racked my brain for a movie with a "ginger helmut." Was stumped.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*[The Guyver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Guyver)* is a 1991 Science Fiction film featuring Mark Hamill which involves a man finding the eponymous device, which is an alien armor. It's based off of a Japanese manga and anime of the name of *[Bio-Booster-Armor Guyver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bio_Booster_Armor_Guyver)*. Could that be what you're thinking of?

[image: The Guyver]

Comment: That's it... Thank you for fixing my horrible memory :)